# XSLT - Passing params from one template to another

Tags: xslt

I am an open-source xslt package for date format conversion.

Link # http://xsltsl.sourceforge.net/

And this is how I call in order to do my date format conversion and obtain date in the following format - April 4, 2011.

```
<xsl:variable name="date.format">%B %d, %Y</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="someDate">
    <xsl:call-template name="dt:format-date-time">
        <xsl:with-param name="xsd-date-time" select="//someDate"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="format" select="$date.format"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

I retrieve the result by call - `<xsl:value-of select="$checkindate"/>`

I would like to update my above code to pass in an additional parameter which is language and be able to get translated values with no luck.

Any help!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to update my above code to pass in an additional
>   parameter which is language and be able to get translated values with
>   no luck.

The `dt:format-date-time` template isn't intended to accept any other parameters than it does at present.

**There is more than one way to achieve the task specified above**:

1. Modify the code of the `dt:format-date-time` template by adding an `xsl:param name="lang" and the corresponding code to process the new parameter.
2. Add a new template (say `dt:format-date-time-NL`). In this template have an `xsl:param name="lang" and, if appropriate, call the existing`dt:format-date-time` template.

**I recommend the second approach** as a positive example of reusing code and achieving flexibility. XSLT provides clean support for this writing style with the standard `xsl:import` and `xsl:include` directives.

Note also, that directly editing someone else's code will not always be possible, desirable or ethical. Even if alowed this can lead to multitude of incompatible "versions" (more exactly "mutations") of the original code with all bad consequences